# ESP32, How can I send data to Index page only when a value changes?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, arduino, esp32

I have used AJAX with XMLHttprequests to get updates from an ESP32 on an interval in the web page already. However I would like to make it so the page doesn't send a request but only receives the data when the ESP32 sees that a value has changed and displays it. How could I go about doing this? I cant find any decent answers but perhaps I dont even know what I should be searching for. Any suggestions are welcome!

esp32 sensor value changes>sends data to webpage>page updates with that data

Comment: server side event? or websocket? or something that doesn't involve HTTP on the ESP32, like mqtt

Comment: send a request from page, but don't send the response from esp32 immediately, but way until the value changes